# creating trigger in java jsp

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I can run the following statement in SQL-developer

```
 String fileInsertTrigger="CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_testtrigger12  "
                                              + "BEFORE INSERT ON user_test1  "
                                              + "FOR EACH ROW  "
                                              + "DECLARE "
                                              + " CNT number ;  "
                                              + " PKV user_test1.PARTY_ID%TYPE ;  "
                                              + "BEGIN  "
                                              + "SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT FROM user_test1 where PARTY_ID like ? and PARTY_ID not like ? ;  "
                                              + "IF CNT=0 THEN  "
                                              + "PKV:= ? ;  "
                                              + " ELSE  "
                                              + "SELECT ? || TRIM(LPAD(MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(PARTY_ID,?,LENGTH(PARTY_ID)))+1),15)) into PKV  "
                                              + "FROM user_test1 where PARTY_ID like ? and PARTY_ID not like ? ;  "
                                              + "END IF ;  "
                                              + ":NEW.PARTY_ID:=PKV ;  "
                                              + "END  " ;
```

and it works perfectly in database after putting all the required values in above query.
when I try to call it from a prepared statement in a jsp I get the following error

SQL Exception;java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 8

According to my analysis it is due to 'NEW' keyword.

```
Connection con=ConnectionDB.getConnection();
            ArrayList dataHolder=FileUploadProcess.readExcelFile(u.getFileName());
         ps=con.prepareStatement(SqlData.getFileinserttrigger());
            System.out.println(u.getExtractString());
            System.out.println(u.getExtractNumber());
            ps.setString(1, u.getExtractString()+"%");
            ps.setString(2, u.getExtractString()+"-%-%");
            ps.setString(3, u.getExtractString()+"2");
            ps.setString(4, u.getExtractString());
            ps.setInt(5, u.getExtractNumber()+1);
            ps.setString(6, u.getExtractString()+"%");
            ps.setString(7, u.getExtractString()+"-%-%");
            ps.executeQuery();
```

Has anybody got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can parametrize the creation DDL of a trigger like this, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Mark is right. You can not pass identifiers as parameters in a `PreparedStatement`. Plus: creating triggers "on the fly" in a JSP page sounds like a horrible idea.